# Vb.net TableLayoutPanel Rows overlapping while every second alternate row control visible true/false

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

**Small overview:-**

(Assuming the row index starts with 1 for better clarity)
I have every odd row (1,3,5...) Drug information.
Every alternate row (2,4,6...) has a special description field which is optional
which i have kept by default visible = false.

So I had kept a button in every first row  (1,3,5...) when clicked the appropriate control TextBox (in next row) visible property is assigned true/false (toggle button).
The second row has only one TextBox control.
Hence when TextBox control is false it is expected that the second row height is automatically zero and when its true the appropriate second row should be visible.

**I have set all the rows height autosize**

**Issue:-

When the button is clicked the TextBox comes overlapped on third row (3,5,7....) instead of displaying on its appropriate second row(2,4,6...) 
When i set the TextBox default visible = true then it takes every second row correctly. But its unnecessary taking a lot of space. As the TextBox entry is optional as said and not required everytime.**

Following are some sreenshots for better more clarity for my issue:-

[image: TableLayoutPanel]

**Fig.1: TableLayout Design**

---

[image: Overlapped on third row instead of taking visible second row]

**Fig.2: Overlapped on third row instead of taking visible second row**

---

[image: When second row TextBox visible is set true by default]

**Fig.3: When second row TextBox visible is set true by default**

---

**My Code behind the button click:-**

```
Private Sub Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_Click(
                                                            sender As Object, e As EventArgs
                                                         ) Handles Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_20.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_19.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_18.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_17.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_16.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_15.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_14.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_13.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_12.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_11.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_10.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_09.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_08.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_07.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_06.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_05.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_04.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_03.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_02.Click,
                                                                    Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_01.Click

    If Initialization_In_Progress = True Then Exit Sub

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_obj
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim btn_Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_obj As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim object_name As String = btn_Button_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_obj.Name
    Dim xCustomer_Selected_srno As Double = object_name.Substring(object_name.Length - 2)
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim txtbox_TextBox_General_Instructions_obj As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox_Drug_Dosage_General_Instructions_" + (xCustomer_Selected_srno).ToString("00"), True)(0), TextBox)
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If txtbox_TextBox_General_Instructions_obj.Visible = False Then

        txtbox_TextBox_General_Instructions_obj.Visible = True
        txtbox_TextBox_General_Instructions_obj.SelectionLength = 0

    Else

        txtbox_TextBox_General_Instructions_obj.Visible = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Hope I have made my best to put the exact issue. If still any further more information is needed I would definately post.

**My other workouts:-**

Tried TextBox Dock Fill, None, Anchor Top,Left, also all, RowHeight Absolute, but nothing worked.

Comment: What is happening makes no sense. What is bothering me is not the wrong order of rows but the fact that you are hiding the `textbox` but it is still visible! You need to make sure that you are setting the visibility to the **correct** `textbox`.

Comment: The TextBox behaves good when set visible to true or false (toggle). There is no issue. In example I have just shown how the rows look when by default I set it to true. Fig.3 is exact I want. But when I set it to false it should not overlap 3rd row like its shown in Fig.2. And my actual design is shown in Fig.1. Still if you need any clarification more, most welcome.

Comment: *...when I set it to false it should not overlap 3rd row...* that is what i said! How is it possible to be **visible** when you set its visibility to **false**! You need to post complete minimal code that reproduces the problem so I can test it.

Comment: But when I set it to **true** it should not overlap 3rd row like its shown in Fig.2
(Corrected the statement)! Secondly! The code is same which I have attached when click a button for optional general instructions (toggle) for if the TextBox is true it would get false and vice versa. If it is true then second row should get visible and if it is false then second row would not be visible **as the TextBox object would be set false and the row height is autosize.** But here in false criteria it works fine but if its true the TextBox is shown overlapped on third row, instead of actual 2nd row!